# Writing data to MSSQL DB (local) using SQLAlchemy: pyodbc error HY104

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm trying to write data from a pandas dataframe to a local MSSQL DB.

The following code works ok up until creation of the table in the DB (cnxn.commit())) but falls down on the final line (the to_sql()).

I'm using VSCode on Windows.

```
"
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Integer, String
 
server='ServerName'
database ='DBName'

conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
    r'SERVER=ServerName;'
    r'DATABASE=DBName;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
fridaypm_test = {'HR': [98, 99, 100, 120, 112], 'Resp': [12, 14, 20, 20, 28], 'SPO2': [99, 99, 100, 99, 100], 'CBT': [36, 36, 36, 37, 38], 'HRV': [20, 30, 25, 36, 78], 'Patient': ['Karim', 'Emma', 'Aziz', 'Swapna', 'Lee']}
fridaypm_test_df = pd.DataFrame(fridaypm_test)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE dbo.FirstTest (HR INT, Resp INT, SPO2 INT, CBT INT, HRV INT, Patient VARCHAR(50))')

cnxn.commit()

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://' + server + '/' + database + '?trusted_connection=yes&driver=SQL+Server')
fridaypm_test_df.to_sql('dbo.FirstTest', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index =False)"
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY104', '[HY104] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid precision value (0) (SQLBindParameter)')        
[SQL: SELECT [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME]
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]
WHERE ([INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_TYPE] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) OR [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_TYPE] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max))) AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max))]   
[parameters: ('BASE TABLE', 'VIEW', 'dbo.FirstTest', 'dbo')]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/dbapi)
```

Originally I thought this might be a problem with my data (I'm using dummy data in the above example) but even with this dummy data, I'm getting the same error.

I've tried it without using sqlalchemy, and I'm getting a similar error when running manual code/ manual sql and using pyodbc alone. It mentions invalid precision values.

I've also tried switching driver from SQL Server to ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server and ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server, but the connection fails every time so these aren't solutions either.

How is this possible when I'm just using INTs?

Can anyone think of an alternative approach?

Comment: "I've also tried switching driver from SQL Server to ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server and ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server, but the connection fails every time so these aren't solutions either." Did you install these drivers?

Comment: So in the error message did you notice `[parameters: ('BASE TABLE', 'VIEW', 'dbo.FirstTest', 'dbo')]` mentions the `dbo` schema twice? Do you think, maybe, that could be significant?

Comment: Like @AlwaysLearning suggests, using `.to_sql('dbo.FirstTest', …)` is incorrect. You need to use  `.to_sql('FirstTest', … , schema='dbo')`

Comment: Yes they're installed. I try to link them to the MS SQL Server DB server using the ODBC Data Sources but they fail every time. SQL Server driver works but I'm not sure if ODBC Drivers are supposed to work with local MS SQL servers. 

Thanks @AlwaysLearning and Gord Thompson but amending this still throws the same error.

Comment: Did you fix your usage of the `to_sql` function yet? You cannot pass a schema name in via the table's `name` parameter, there's a seperate `schema` parameter for that. Ref: [pandas.DataFrame.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)